# Restart pod when another service is recreated

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a flask pod that connects to a mongodb service through the environment variable SERVICE_HOST (DNS discovery didn't work for some reason), when I change something in mongodb service and re-apply it, the flask pod won't be able to connect to the service anymore since the service host changes, I have to recreate it everytime manually, is there a way to automate this, sort of like docker-compose depends_on directive ?

*flask yaml*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: proxy23-api-deployment
  labels:
    app: proxy23-api
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: proxy23-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: proxy23-api
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: proxy23-api
          image: my_image
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: DB_URI
              value: mongodb://$(PROXY23_DB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST):27017
            - name: DB_NAME
              value: db
            - name: PORT
              value: "5000"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-credentials
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: proxy23-api-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: proxy23-api
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9002
      targetPort: 5000
      nodePort: 30002
```

*mongodb yaml*

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: proxy23-db-deployment
  labels:
    app: proxy23-db
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: proxy23-db
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: proxy23-db
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: proxy23-db
          image: mongo:bionic
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          volumeMounts:
            - name: proxy23-storage
              mountPath: /data/db
      volumes:
        - name: proxy23-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: proxy23-db-pvc
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: proxy23-db-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: proxy23-db
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
      nodePort: 30003
```

Comment: Can you share yaml of mongodb and flask app deployment?

Comment: Your MongoDB Service should have its own VIP. If internal DNS resolution somehow does not work, you can get your that Services ClusterIP (kubectl get svc), and use it instead of a DNS name. kube-proxy is meant to update firewalling on Kubernetes nodes, so whenever you restart your MongoDB pod, it should re-route connections to your new Pod IP.

Comment: @Ali I included the yaml files in the question

Comment: @SYN but If I recreate the mongodb service its cluster ip would change aswell

Comment: Usually if you redeploy the Service its cluster-internal IP address won't change.  But the real answer should be to use the `proxy23-db-service.namespace.svc.cluster.local` host name; what doesn't work if you try it?

Comment: You can add livenessprobe to the flask pod using the same service_host variable. It will restart the pod if the service is not reachable.

Also, Iike other suggested above, i would recreate the service as clusterip and use the service name to connect to db from flask.

Comment: @DavidMaze if you simply kubectl apply the cluster ip won't change, but what if I delete the service and recreate it, in that case it will.
DNS discovery doesn't work, for some reason it timeout, that's why I went with env vars instead

Comment: Concentrate on fixing the DNS issue (which is probably a cluster-administration issue, not a programming problem) rather than working around it.  The Service DNS name will be stable even if you delete and reapply it (it's under your control) and you shouldn't have to restart downstream services (assuming they use DNS correctly).

Comment: @WytrzymalyWiktor no none so far

Comment: Hello @LonelyDaoist. Have you tried David's suggestions? Try to debug DNS like described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/).

Comment: Hi @WytrzymalyWiktor I tried that link but I haven't figured it out yet, nslookup just times out

Comment: Have you managed to make it work ?
Could you please follow all the steps in this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) and report the results.

Comment: Hi @matt_j, it still doesn't work, as I said I already tried that link, nslookup keeps timing out